# array length on multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

for the follwing code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  String[][] fruits = {{"orange", "pear", "banana", "pinapple" "grape"},
                     {"apple", "kiwi", "strawberry", "plum"}};

  String[] veggies = {"okra","pumpkin", "spinach", "brockoli"};


  System.out.println(fruits.length); 
  System.out.println(veggies.length);

  }
```

`System.out.println(veggies.length);` prints out 4 because there are 4 elements.

`System.out.println(fruits.length);` prints out 2, why ? should it not be 9 because there are 9 elements.

Comment: fruits[0].length will return 5, fruits[1].length will return 4

Comment: No, a multidimensional array is an array of arrays. So it's logical that it'd return 2 since it's the number of arrays in the array.

Comment: perhaps better: s/multi/two/

Answer (score 1):

To print length of multidimensional (n) array you should use (n) loops.

so you should use:

```
String[][] fruits = {{"orange", "pear", "banana", "pinapple" "grape"},
                 {"apple", "kiwi", "strawberry", "plum"}};
int length = 0;
for(int i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
  length += fruits[i].length;
 }
System.out.println(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fruits` is, like you said, a multidimensional array, or simply an array of arrays.
In the example you gave fruits holds 2 arrays in him, hence his length is 2.
If you want to know how much "fruits" are inside, I'd suggest you sum the length of each array inside `fruits`.

Answer (score 0):

`fruits.length` only gives you the number of elements stored in fruits. How many is that? Only two. Fruits contains **two** elements. They just happen to be arrays containing other items:

```
{"orange", "pear", "banana", "pinapple" "grape"}
{"apple", "kiwi", "strawberry", "plum"}
```

So, to get the length of each array:

```
fruits[0].length
fruits[1].length
```

Answer (score 0):

fruits is a two dimensional array, fruits.length only gives you the length of the first dimension.

fruits[0].length + fruits[1].length  will give you 9 then

Answer (score 0):

It's because `fruits` has two arrays stored within that array, first of length 5 and the second of length 4. 
If you simply call:

`System.out.println(fruits.length);`

it will return the length of the objects that are in that array (2 arrays).

If you wanted to get the length of the first array within `fruits`, you would call

`System.out.println(fruits[0].length);`,

which will print out 5. And if you were to call

`System.out.println(fruits[1].length);`,

it will print out 4.

Answer (score -1):

Because, `fruits` a two dimensional array.

Comment: two dimensions != two elements

Comment: The fact that the array is *two*-dimensional does not explain why "it prints out 2" - your statement is confusing.